# mongoose model value and merging new object not working in node js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am a beginner in mean stack development. I am trying to fetch records from a collection and add two more objects in the records but I can't merge the objects.

I have tried the following. Not getting the values of the "images" objects which I tried to merge with "projects" object. It's not merging.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
project.findOne({_id:id}).exec(function (err, projectdetails) {

  if(err){
    res.send(err);
  }


            projectimage.find({projectId: projectdetails._id}, function(err, data){
              if(err){
                res.send(err);
              }


var projects = projectdetails;

var images = [
   {
     image_id : 1,
    "image_location" : "f1.js"
   },
    {
     image_id : 2,
    "image_location" : "f2.js"
   } 

];
 projects = _.extend({},projects,{images:images},{projectimage:data});

        res.send(projects);

            });



    });
```

obtained output:

```
{
  "_id": "58da3c350a668f13f0d6dbcc",
  "name": "senthil",
  "designation": "CI",
  "berief_text": "welcome to senthil",
  "status": 1,
  "__v": 0
}
```

expected output:

```
{
  "_id": "58da3c350a668f13f0d6dbcc",
  "name": "senthil",
  "designation": "CI",
  "berief_text": "welcome to senthil",
  "status": 1,
  "__v": 0,
  "images": [
    {
      "image_id": 1,
      "image_location": "f1.js"
    },
    {
      "image_id": 2,
      "image_location": "f2.js"
    }
  ],
  "projectimage": [
    {
      "_id": "58da3c350a668f13f0d6dbcd",
      "imageLocation": "uploads\\project_images\\1490697269435download.jpg",
      "projectId": "58da3c350a668f13f0d6dbcc",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "58da3c350a668f13f0d6dbce",
      "imageLocation": "uploads\\project_images\\1490697269439download (3).jpg",
      "projectId": "58da3c350a668f13f0d6dbcc",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(projects)) 
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(images))
```

before

```
projects = _.extend({},projects,{images:images},{projectimage:data});
```